# Is there a way to specify a local user to migrate on User State Migration Tool (USMT)

Tags: windows, cmd, local, usmt

Is there a way to only migrate select local accounts when using the USMT tool.

This is the command I use, but it does all local accounts, not specific ones.

scanstate \workdocs /i:migapp.xml /i:migdocs.xml /i:miguser.xml /o /v:13 /localonly /c /uel:30 /efs:copyraw

Answer (score 0):

From my research the only way would be to limit the scope of users by /uel option.

The /uel switch replaces the /user option from previous version of USMT. It allows you to migrate only users that have logged into the source computer within a specific amount of time. This prevents you from transferring data from users who may have logged into that machine for some reason in the distant path, but most likely do not need their profiles moved.